# Period over period SQL script?

Tags: sql, scripting, domo

I have a dataset of 2 columns: 'Date' and 'Total Sales'. My dates are 01-01-2021, 02-01-2021... so on and so forth up until 12-01-2022. I basically want to add another row where I have a "previous month" column that gives me the total sales for the previous month in the same row as the current month (else null) -- e.g. say I have 2 rows in my date column 01-01-2021 and 02-01-2021 and total sales would be $10 and $20 respectively. How do can I create a column that would show the following:

```
Date       |Sales | Previous Month Sales|
---------------------------------------------
01-01-2021 | $10  | null
02-01-2021 | $20  | $10
```

So on and so forth; this is my query:

```
CASE 

WHEN `Date` > DATE_SUB(`Date`, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 

THEN `Monthly Sales`

ELSE 'null'

END
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Well, Domo's back-end **is** running a MySQL back-engine (from what I recall the last time I touched Domo [2018])

I think this is just a SQL question, and I wonder if a simple windowing function would do the trick.

```
select Date,
       Sales,
       max (case when *month* = *this month -1* then Sales else null end) over (order by 1) as "Previous Month Sales"
   from table
```

You just need to figure out how to break down the Date into the month based on whatever SQL dialect Domo uses nowadays.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think domo support MySQL-like language, so you could do something like this:

```
    with cte as
    (
    select date, 
      date + interval 1 month as next_month, 
      sales
    from sales
    )
    select a.date, 
    a.sales as current_sales, 
    b.sales as prior_month_sales
    from sales a
    left join cte b
      on b.next_month = a.date
    order by a.date
```

Comment: Thank you -- I'm actually trying to do this from a beast mode though which doesn't support all MySQL functions I think?

Answer (score 1):

I do this by joining the table onto itself with a LEFT OUTER JOIN. The outer join allows you to keep the null value for previous month. You match the date such that 1 column is calculated to show the previous month (I do this with EOMONTH() to ensure I always get the previous month and account for the year, if say it is January).

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP

CREATE TABLE #TEMP(
    [Date]          DATE
    ,[Sales]        INT
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP([Date],[Sales])
VALUES ('2020-12-20',50)
    ,('2021-01-20',100)
    ,('2021-02-20',200)
    ,('2021-03-20',300)
    ,('2021-04-20',400)
    ,('2021-05-20',500)

SELECT #TEMP.[Date]
    ,#TEMP.Sales
    ,TEMPII.Date [PREV M]
    ,TEMPII.Sales [PREV M SALES]
FROM #TEMP
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #TEMP TEMPII
        ON YEAR(EOMONTH(#TEMP.[Date],-1))*100+MONTH(EOMONTH(#TEMP.[Date],-1)) = YEAR(TEMPII.[Date])*100+MONTH(TEMPII.[Date])
ORDER BY #TEMP.[Date]
```

Output: [image]